# How can I stop my Jitter physics meshes being offset?

Tags: c#, physics, xna-4.0

I'm developing a C# game engine and have hit a snag trying to add physics. I'm using XNA for graphics and Jitter for physics. I am trying to split the XNA model into it's meshes, then create a `ConvexHull` for each mesh. I then attempt to combine those into a `CompoundObject`, this however isn't working and depending upon the model the meshes are offset by different amounts.

[This](http://pastebin.com/PNkWVfsz) is the code I'm currently using and it gives me:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Ben, if you figured this out by now you can add it as answer and accept it.